# Does a Windows 8 Modern-UI app need a main page?

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

I'd like to implement a File Picker Contract provider so that other applications can open files from my web service.  Other than providing the UI in response to File Open, there's no need for the app to have its own interface - no need for its own main page that shows when launched from the Start screen.  In fact, it'd probably be best if the app didn't even show itself on the Start screen.

Is this possible and are there samples or documentation I can follow for this?  Thanks, I'm having a hard time finding the answer through the doc pages I've seen so far.

Comment: I can't say for certain, but that sounds like something that isn't a metro app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your app will pass certification if you create something that doesn't have an interface. In fact, as far as I know, you need to show a UI within a certain amount of time for the app to not be suspended/shut-down by the OS / runtime.

In other words - yes an app needs a main page / UI.

Are you sure you really need a Metro / Modern UI app at all in your situation? Perhaps a desktop app with appropriate file associations set up should do?

Comment: Thanks, Krishna. Yes, I do want a Metro / Modern UI app.  Over time, we probably will have an interface.  But for our first release we basically want a way to open/save a file, say from the Mail or Photos app, to our cloud solution using the File Open/Save Contracts idiom.  So we do have an interface, but just when we're responding to the contract invocation.  Does that make sense? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx

Comment: Yes it does. Perhaps you could just have a static page when someone opens your app directly from the main page. The page could then have some help / guidance for the user on how/when to use the app? Or may be show a list of files selected previously, like a history?

Comment: Yep, we can definitely figure out what to put there.  Unfortunately it'll take more time than we'd like.  I fear a fairly useless main page like some static text wouldn't be very compelling to a user.  Thanks again.